# Does article 8 of the European Convention protect against the dissemination of sensitive information about a research subject in scientific research?

Tags: privacy, data-protection, research, european-convention-on-human-rights

I have a couple of questions related to the scope of Article 8(1) of the European Convention on Human Rights and who can be responsible for infringements in the rights outlined in the article. My first question is if the state's positive or negative obligations to refrain from breaches of the rights in article 8 covers such acts conducted by universities or higher research institutions, for example research conducted by an affiliated researcher. Second, if the collection and dissemination of sensitive personal data (that is not medical data) about an identifiable person through the researching and publishing of a scholarly article interferes with that person's right to respect for private life, and, if so, the responsibility for the interference lies with the individual researcher or the institution which permitted and published the research or both.

Please cite or refer to relevant case law of the European Court of Human Rights or the Court of Justice of the European Union or another relevant institution.